# How can I see total time today on _all project_ in the modeline?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The variable `org-clock-modeline-total` gives me several options for what time to show in the modeline, but they limited to time clocked into the current task. I would like to show the total time clock into all tasks in a particular subtree. Is that possible?

Comment: Repeated the question on the new beta Emacs site: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/1035/925